# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--c

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::_*construct() [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse
>   time string (Resource id #7) at position 0 (R): The timezone could not
>   be found in the database' in Z:\home\plati\www\view.php:21 Stack
>   trace: #0 Z:\home\plati\www\view.php(21):
>   DateTime->*_construct('Resource id #7') #1 {main} thrown in
>   Z:\home\plati\www\view.php on line 21

have ithis error what do?
line 20...

```
$date = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM sondaje WHERE id = '$id'") or die("Error! DataBase Name Incorrect!");
$bdate = new DateTime("$date");
$bdate->modify('+8 day');
$yearz = $bdate->format('Y');
$monthz = $bdate->format('m');
$dayz = $bdate->format('d');
$hourz = $bdate->format('H');
$minutz = $bdate->format('i');
$secndz = $bdate->format('s');
```

Comment: Sorry but Stack Overflow is not a convenient alternative to reading the manual. There're plenty of examples on how to use the (obsolete) mysql extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to fetch the data from as [`mysql_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns only link identifier, from manual:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.

```
$fetch_date = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM sondaje WHERE id = '$id'") 
             or die("Error! DataBase Name Incorrect!");

$date = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch_date);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't do this on purpose. I can't revoke if you don't edit... strange.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch the result before using it as variable!

```
$bdate = new DateTime(mysql_result($result, 0, 0));
```

See [mysql_result()](http://php.net/mysql_result)